# Animate widgets inside a horizontal ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Consider a horizontally scrollable ListView where each item is a Stack. The Stack has two widgets, a larger blue Container on the bottom, and a smaller amber Container on top. When I tap the blue Container the amber Container should move to the right outside the blue one, shifting the rest of the items inside the list to the right. How can I do this?

```
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: 5,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 120,
                    width: 90,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 90,
                  width: 30,
                  color: Colors.amber,
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
  },
),
```

Screenshots:
[image: Initial state, before the blue Container has been tapped]
[image: Final state, after the blue Container has been tapped]

Comment: Please clarify a bit better what you are trying to do, this "When I tap the blue Container the amber Container should move to the right outside the blue one, shifting the rest of the items to the right.", after trying your code, is difficult to understand. You want the whole list view to move, or the individual items?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've added some screenshots to make it more clear.

Comment: Have you attempted the answer below? If it solved your issue, please mark it as correct, and consider upvoting for visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is scroll the content back to the beginning of the `ListView`, then the following code will do it:

```
class ScrollAnimation61190061 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScrollAnimation61190061State createState() => _ScrollAnimation61190061State();
}

class _ScrollAnimation61190061State extends State<ScrollAnimation61190061> {
  final int _listLength = 5;
  List<EdgeInsets> _itemInsets = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _itemInsets = List.generate(_listLength, (index) => null);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: _listLength,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
                height: 120,
                width: 90,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _itemInsets[index] = EdgeInsets.only(left: 60);
                });
              },
            ),
            Container(
              margin: _itemInsets[index],
              height: 90,
              width: 30,
              color: Colors.amber,
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What I actually want is one element of the stack to change its position within the ListView itself, and not move the contents of the whole screen. I've attached some screenshots to make it more clear.

Comment: @vaishnav I've changed the code to move each individual amber box to the right side of the blue Container.